# Why is this :icontaining code so flow on IE 8, but quick on Firefox, Chrome and Opera

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, filter

The code below is used to initially display `<div>` elements with a logo, a name and some links.

When entering characters info the filter field, only those `<div>` elements containing the characters entered are displayed ( the rest are hidden ).

The `:icontains` is a case insensitive variant of the `:contains` filter.

On Firefox, Chrome and Opera, typing characters filters the `<div>` elements immediatly (50 miliseconds or so). Doing the same on IE 8, takes almost 5000 miliseconds .

The code below only shows a couple of `<div class='linken2col filterbaar'>`. On the page I am using it for, I have about 150 `<div>` elements.

Any one any idea what can cause the problem in IE 8 ( I haven't tried it in IE 9, but I suspect a lot of visitors of my web site are still using IE 8 anyway ). It would be a pity to not being able to use this code just because Microsoft does something awkward with Javascript code.

```
  <form name="searchBox">
     Zoek naar <input type="text" name="filterargument" id="filterargument" />
     <input type="button" value="filter..." />
     <i>(deel van de) clubnaam , de federatie of het clubnr</i>
  </form>

  <div class='volledige-breedte floatleft'>

  <div class='linken2col filterbaar'><a href='http://www.staplijst.com/wsv-wetteren.asp' target='staplijst_link'><img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/groot/010.jpg' class='logo100' alt='WSV Wetteren AKTIVIA 010' align='left'></a><a href='http://www.staplijst.com/wsv-wetteren.asp' target='staplijst_link'><b>WSV Wetteren</b></a>&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/staplijst-zonnetje.gif' class='inline-icon16' alt='licentiehouder van Staplijst'><br><br>AKTIVIA 010<br><div style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.staplijst.be/wandelclub-wsv-wetteren-aktivia-010.asp'>alle statistieken en grafieken&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/btngrafiek24.png' class='inline-icon24' alt='wandelstatistieken, uitslagen en grafieken voor WSV Wetteren AKTIVIA 010'></a></div></div>
  <div class='linken2col filterbaar'><a href='http://www.wandelclubegmont.be' target='staplijst_link'><img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/groot/163.jpg' class='logo100' alt='WSV Egmont - Zottegem AKTIVIA 163' align='left'></a><a href='http://www.wandelclubegmont.be' target='staplijst_link'><b>WSV Egmont - Zottegem</b></a>&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/staplijst-zonnetje.gif' class='inline-icon16' alt='licentiehouder van Staplijst'><br><br>AKTIVIA 163<br><div style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.staplijst.be/wandelclub-wsv-egmont-uit-zottegem-aktivia-163.asp'>alle statistieken en grafieken&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/btngrafiek24.png' class='inline-icon24' alt='wandelstatistieken, uitslagen en grafieken voor WSV Egmont - Zottegem AKTIVIA 163'></a></div></div>


  <div class='linken2col filterbaar'><a href='http://www.zandstappers.be' target='staplijst_link'><img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/groot/A044.jpg' class='logo100' alt='Wandelclub Zandstappers v.z.w. VWF A044' align='left'></a><a href='http://www.zandstappers.be' target='staplijst_link'><b>Wandelclub Zandstappers v.z.w.</b></a>&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/staplijst-zonnetje.gif' class='inline-icon16' alt='licentiehouder van Staplijst'><br><br>VWF A044<br><div style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.staplijst.be/wandelclub-zandstappers-uit-wechelderzande-vwf-a044.asp'>alle statistieken en grafieken&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/btngrafiek24.png' class='inline-icon24' alt='wandelstatistieken, uitslagen en grafieken voor Wandelclub Zandstappers v.z.w. VWF A044'></a></div></div>
  <div class='linken2col filterbaar'><a href='http://www.waterhoekstappers.be' target='staplijst_link'><img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/groot/345.jpg' class='logo100' alt='De Waterhoekstappers - Heestert AKTIVIA 345' align='left'></a><a href='http://www.waterhoekstappers.be' target='staplijst_link'><b>De Waterhoekstappers - Heestert</b></a>&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/staplijst-zonnetje.gif' class='inline-icon16' alt='licentiehouder van Staplijst'><br><br>AKTIVIA 345<br><div style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.staplijst.be/wandelclub-waterhoekstappers-uit-heestert-aktivia-345.asp'>alle statistieken en grafieken&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/btngrafiek24.png' class='inline-icon24' alt='wandelstatistieken, uitslagen en grafieken voor De Waterhoekstappers - Heestert AKTIVIA 345'></a></div></div>


  <div class='linken2col filterbaar'><a href='http://www.stormvogels.be' target='staplijst_link'><img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/groot/070.jpg' class='logo100' alt='WSV De StormVogels vzw Oostende AKTIVIA 070' align='left'></a><a href='http://www.stormvogels.be' target='staplijst_link'><b>WSV De StormVogels vzw Oostende</b></a>&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/staplijst-zonnetje.gif' class='inline-icon16' alt='licentiehouder van Staplijst'><br><br>AKTIVIA 070<br><div style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.staplijst.be/wandelclub-stormvogels-uit-oostende-aktivia-070.asp'>alle statistieken en grafieken&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/btngrafiek24.png' class='inline-icon24' alt='wandelstatistieken, uitslagen en grafieken voor WSV De StormVogels vzw Oostende AKTIVIA 070'></a></div></div>
  <div class='linken2col filterbaar'><a href='http://www.wandelmee.be' target='staplijst_link'><img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/groot/A054.jpg' class='logo100' alt='wandelmee.be VWF A054' align='left'></a><a href='http://www.wandelmee.be' target='staplijst_link'><b>wandelmee.be</b></a>&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/staplijst-zonnetje.gif' class='inline-icon16' alt='licentiehouder van Staplijst'><br><br>VWF A054<br><div style='text-align:center;'><a href='http://www.staplijst.be/wandelmee.asp'>alle statistieken en grafieken&nbsp;<img src='http://www.staplijst.be/images/btngrafiek24.png' class='inline-icon24' alt='wandelstatistieken, uitslagen en grafieken voor wandelmee.be VWF A054'></a></div></div>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
         /* ---- extra selector "icontains" registreren ------------------------------ */
         jQuery.expr[':'].icontains = function(a, i, m) {
            return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
         };

         var $filterArgument =  $("#filterargument");

         $('#filterargument').keyup(
            function() { performFilter(); }
         );

         function performFilter() {
            /*var filterArgument = $("#filterargument").val();*/
            var filterArgument = $filterArgument.val();

            var t1 = +new Date;

            if (filterArgument === '') {
               $('.filterbaar').show(); }
            else {
               $('.filterbaar:not(:icontains("' + filterArgument + '"))').hide();
               $('.filterbaar:icontains("' + filterArgument + '")').show();
            }

            var t2 = +new Date;
            alert ( filterArgument + ':' + (t2 - t1) + ' miliseconds');

         }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only variable that has changed is the browser (using IE8 is the only difference) then this is just an example of begging the question. IE8 takes so long because IE8 is slow.

In some cases, alternative approaches might use JS that is more optimized, but I honestly don't know what functions you'd have to swap out to even begin guessing.

Comment: Stating the obvious, is not helping me to solve the problem :) I looked at my statistics: 70% of my visitors are still using IE and 53% from those are using IE 8.

Comment: I understand that it doesn't magically solve your problem, but it IS the answer. "Why is my bicycle slower than this Porsche?" Well, because it's slower. The technology isn't the same.

Comment: +Greg Pettit: I know (I have been programming far too long not to know this, believe me). I also know that most of the times, you have different ways of accomplish your goal. Since jQuery is supposed to be browser independent, I am sure that I, as a beginner in jQuery programming, have not used the correct or fastest way. So I was hoping for some answer from more jQuery knowledgable persons. I will try the solution with arrays as suggested by @Kevin B.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if it is any better:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].icontains = function(a, i, m) {
  return (a.textContent || a.innerText || getText([ a ]) || "")
    .toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

Edit: actually, i need to modify that code, you dont have access to `elem` or `match` in the same way that the core does.

more than likely it won't be any faster, but it is the way that the native :contains is implemented.

Edit: To actually make it faster in IE, you may need to represent the elements in an object or array, then do all of your filtering using that array rather than html elements. You can then show elements based on the array/object. This method is very similar to how datatable plugins allow sorting and filtering that is still fast enough to be acceptable in IE.

Edit for comment:
This is how i would implement the filtering with an array:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/Ju6TF/1/

```
var $filterArgument =  $("#filterargument");
var filterCache = $.map($(".filterbaar"),function(el){
    return {
        el: el,
        text: (el.textContent || el.innerText || $.find.getText([ el ]) || "").toUpperCase()
    };
});
$('#filterargument').keyup(performFilter);
function performFilter() {
    /*var filterArgument = $("#filterargument").val();*/
    var filterArgument = $filterArgument.val();
    var t1 = +new Date;
    $('.filterbaar').show();
    if (filterArgument === '') {
        return;
    }
    else {
        $(filterCache).filter(function(el){
            return this.text.indexOf(filterArgument.toUpperCase()) == -1;  
        }).each(function(){
            $(this.el).hide(); 
        });
    }
    var t2 = +new Date;
    alert( filterArgument + ':' + (t2 - t1) + ' miliseconds');
}
```

Comment: I upvote you if you can show me some code using an object or an array. Although I find it a pity to have to resort to such things just because one of the browsers implements the javascript engine in wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Will try it later and let you know the results.